# Normalization problem when running my image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, normalization

I am trying to normalize the images and used the following code to do that but when trying to normalize

```
img = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

when I print the image using print(img)

i get the following as if No normalization was applied to the image

```
[[199 204 205 ...  29  30  34]
 [195 200 203 ...  30  30  32]
 [190 195 200 ...  35  31  29]
 ...
 [  7   3   1 ...  16  16  15]
 [ 19  13   7 ...  18  18  17]
 [ 35  26  19 ...  18  20  19]]
```

I tried to use another approach as

```
img/255 or img/255.0.
```

I still can see black images and upon printing print(img) I get the following as:

```
[[0.78039216 0.8        0.80392157 ... 0.11372549 0.11764706 0.13333333]
 [0.76470588 0.78431373 0.79607843 ... 0.11764706 0.11764706 0.1254902 ]
 [0.74509804 0.76470588 0.78431373 ... 0.1372549  0.12156863 0.11372549]
```

I am kind of confused on why I get the black images ?
...

Comment: Min/Max normalization maps the darkest values to 0 and the brightest values to 255. But if you input already has values of 0 and 255 (even for one pixel each), then there will be no change.

Comment: “as if No normalization was applied to the image” Please describe why you think this. It should help us understand where your issue is. “see black images” How do you display them?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have very small areas with luminosity that is very close to 255. That will "halt" the normalization.

What you can do is use some kind of **thresholding** to remove, say, all intensities from 220 to 255 and map them to 220. If you normalize *that*, the points with intensity 220 will be driven up to 255, but *this* time the darker values will get amplified too.

However, I think you're likely to get better answers if you describe in more detail what you're trying to accomplish - what the image is, and to what end you want to normalize it.